# Flutter: wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Could not download wasm module

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm building a Flutter web app. Everything was working fine until randomly I did a hot restart and then I began getting this error.

> wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Could not download wasm module

Tried 2 things

1. Reverted the code back to a known working state (from git source control) and I still get this error.
2. Created NEW Flutter project from Android studio using New Flutter project options. Still did not work.

Any ideas? I tried to update Chrome and this did not help.

Comment: Eventually it started working again. No idea how I fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

I lived in a remote area where no broadband is available so I use wireless network through sim card. The operator network is disturbing ,I can browse website sometimes and some times bit laggy on the other hand my flutter project work on emulator but I can not run it web. I changed the operator network and get a good quality of internet connection than The issue gone. What I think some module in web need to build good internet connection. I don't know this answer is helpful or not but this is how I solve my issue

Comment: thank you for sharing how you solved it! For me I didn't have a good idea why it started working again. Hope someone comes along and can explain why it happens

Answer (score 1):

It needs a stable internet connection to run. The error gone once I switched to good internet.